# Updating __init__ elements through a class method in Python

Tags: python, class

I have a class that takes a list of strings as an argument and I would like to have
my class methods update the element in the **init** method. Not sure if this is possible or bad practice, but any advice would be really appreciated! The code would be like:

```
class TextList:
    def __init__(self, listofstrings):
         self.strings = listofstrings

    def my_method(self):
        newstrings = [i.strip() for i in self.strings]
        # code that updates 'self.strings' to equal 'newstrings'
```

So that I could run:

```
mylist = TextList(mylistofstrings)
mylist = mylist.my_method()
```

And mylist.strings would equal the output of 'my_method'

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to update the existing list, you can do that directly.

```
def my_method(self):
    self.strings = [i.strip() for i in self.strings]
```

Since this method updates `self.strings` directly, there is no need to return anything.

```
>>> mylist = TextList(["hi\n", "bye\n"])
>>> mylist.strings
['hi\n', 'bye\n']
>>> mylist.my_method()
>>> mylist.strings
['hi', 'bye']
```

Comment: Perfect answer, I would just add that if OP _does_ want to return a copy of the object with `mylist = mylist.my_method()`, for whatever reason, they can add `return self` to `my_method`